# How to get /actuator/quartz metrics from code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, spring-boot-actuator

I would like to implement liveness health indicator which will base on data described here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.7/actuator-api/htmlsingle/#quartz.trigger-group

My goal is to access this data from the same application which expose this endpoint, from code.

I'm using: Spring Boot 2.6.7

I tried to retrieve it from `MeterRegistry` but there are no "quartz" related metrics.

I care most about these 2 metrics:

```
"previousFireTime" : "2020-12-04T03:00:00.000+00:00",
"nextFireTime"     : "2020-12-07T03:00:00.000+00:00",
```

I know that I can get nextFireTime and previousFireTime from `JobExecutionContext` in Job implementation class but in our service this method:

```
  @Override
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) {
  ...
  }
```

Randomly stop executing and the role of this health indicator will be to detect it.

Comment: Try to have a look at how the quartz actuator endpoint is implement and see if you can fetch the same information, see this link for the source code: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1c8bd93fe5fd79b4499e313133ebfb2bce3b6bc1/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/quartz/QuartzEndpoint.java#L115